# How do I make npm install work when it can't find my python installation?

Tags: node.js, macos, python-2.7, npm, npm-install

`npm install` fails and my goal is to get it to succeed.

I have Python 2 installed, but it is located at `/usr/bin/python2` and not `/usr/local/bin/python2`.

I get the following error message when running `npm install`.

```
gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
gyp verb cli ]
gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
gyp info using node@14.2.0 | darwin | x64
gyp verb command rebuild []
gyp verb command clean []
gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
gyp verb command configure []
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "/usr/local/bin/python2" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: /usr/local/bin/python2
```

What should I do about it?

Answer (score 0):

One of the simplest things you can try is a symlink from the actual location of the `python2` executable to the location where `npm` is expecting it.

```sh
# create symlink
ln -s /usr/bin/python2 /usr/local/bin/python2

# test executability of symlink
/usr/local/bin/python2 --version
```

Once you've created that symlink, retry `npm install` in your project.